# Python datetime to utc conversion mistake

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have time in file in `05:55:13` format and I want to add current date to it making `2017-04-27`. Then I want to have it in UTC format for grafana but there seems to be rounding off. How will this work?

I get same output for `05:55:13` and `05:56:13`.

```
import datetime
import time

line =  str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + "05:55:13"
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
utc_dt = naive.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print naive
print utc_dt

line =  str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + "05:56:13"
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
utc_dt = naive.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print naive
print utc_dt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `utcnow`, which [returns current date and time in `UTC` timezone](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow). Of course you got identical outputs. Use your code without this method:

```
line =  str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + "05:55:13"
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
utc_dt = naive.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print naive
print utc_dt

line =  str(datetime.date.today()) + " " + "05:56:13"
naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
utc_dt = naive.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print naive
print utc_dt
```

Comment: I there any way I can move *naive* back or forward by timezone?

Comment: You can use the `timezone` property and `astimezone` method, see more in linked docs.

Comment: Thanks. Actually using timezone messed up influxdb and grafana. So I did timedelta  datetime.timedelta(hours=5,minutes=15)